# mcelog: Cannot access bus threshold trigger `bus-error-trigger': Permission denied

Tags: cron, centos, vps, plesk

Since this weekend I get a mail every hour from my server with the following message:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/mcelog.cron:

mcelog: Cannot access bus threshold trigger `bus-error-trigger': Permission denied

With the subject: "Cron <root@s1> run-parts /etc/cron.hourly"
```

On my VPS I run `CentOS 6.7` and `Plesk v12.0.18`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks, Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this on a couple of Plesk servers with SELinux enabled. The problem is that the security contexts of the scripts under /etc/mcelog are incorrect, so SELinux prevents mcelog from executing them. To fix this, run the following commands as root:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t '/etc/mcelog/.*-error-trigger'
# restorecon -R /etc/mcelog
```

(If the semanage command is not available, install the policycoreutils-python package. You could just use chcon, but this would not survive a filesystem relabel.)

See: http://forum.odin.com/threads/mcelog-cron-error.334110/

Comment: Thanks for the solution!